# D3 js Collision detection for different shapes and Foreign Objects

Tags: d3.js, collision-detection, radial

I'm fairly new to D3 and have been tasked with developing a force directed graph, however this diagram is unlike any examples I have found and I seem to have encountered quite a few issues.

I'm trying to develop something like this:

http://www.huzzahstudios.com/images/profile_page_simple.jpg

The biggest problem I am having so far is that the nodes containing text tend to overlap quite considerably and collision detection on the shape they form does not seem to be functioning as expected.

Basically I need:

```
- Nodes to never overlap in resolved state
- Nodes to resolve in similar locations (as per diagram above)
- Graph to be able to adapt acceptably depending on amount of data
```

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/lucidlyle/SwV9s/4/

As you can see it's very messy at the moment, any help with this matter would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add the code as well along with the jsFiddle.

Comment: You may get a better response (and better fit the Q&A format) if you stick to one question.